# Android error "unable to find explicit activity class"

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have an android project with several packages. The structure of the packages in this case is com.WAPP.SetLocation is the package that contains the activity I want to run.

In my manifest, com.WAPP is considered the base package:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.WAPP"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
```

My activities are declared in my manifest as:

```
<activity android:name=".mainScreenActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name=".SetLocation.setLocationActivity"></activity>
```

The mainScreen activity displays fine, since it is inside the com.WAPP package. But when I try to run the setLocationActivity, I get the unable to find explicit class error. Here is how I have the intent parameters:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.WAPP.SetLocation",
                           "com.WAPP.SetLocation.setLocationActivity");
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 31):

The first parameter is **application package** not the package where the activity is.

You can invoke the Activity like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.WAPP",
               "com.WAPP.SetLocation.setLocationActivity");
startActivity(i);
```

It is preferred as SYLARRR suggested to have Android automatically figure that out for you. Hence the call as..

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, setLocationActivity.class));
```

It's recommended per java standards to have the package name all lower-cased and the class name as CamelCased.

Comment: Hi Sir, is there any permanent solution to this problem? I face this issue always whenever I create a package.

Answer (score 20):

If the new activity not in the same packet with MainActivity(you call from here?), try declare on manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.WAPP.SetLocation.setLocationActivity"></activity>
```

and in the caller

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, setLocationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

In additional to the above answers make sure that your activities are declared inside application in manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <activity android:name=".mainScreenActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SetLocation.setLocationActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: That was the problem I had. Was doing a hackathon and copied a lot of files so Android Studio never had a chance to pick up on the new activity.

Answer (score 4):

If i'm not mistaken, the `i.setClassName("com.WAPP.SetLocation","com.WAPP.SetLocation.setLocationActivity");` should be `i.setClassName(getBaseContext(),"setLocationActivity");` [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29)

Also try this syntax:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, setLocationActivity.class));
```

and try removing the starting dot from:

```
<activity android:name=".SetLocation.setLocationActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it by this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(
        new ComponentName("com.WAPP", "com.WAPP.SetLocation.setLocationActivity"));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should class ad to manifest.xml
for example of `manifest.xml`
in this example, i added `SecondActivity.class`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: how can your both activities be main & launcher activities ?

Comment: That is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Android, make sure that your Activity class has an Activity attribute

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
public class MyActivity : ActivityBase
{
...
}
```

With that you are making sure that your activity is registered in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of issue in the project . It wasted me almost a full day . i tried all the solutions that are mentioned above , but none of the solutions worked for me . 
After all the hard work i just "Rebuild" the project and "clean" The project and it worked perfectly . 
Note:
 Before going through all the process u just needed to have a try to these options.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that you have created activity and not the class. And, if it is activity then go to the **manifest.xml** file and look at the **path** of that particular file.

This worked for me absolutely well!!

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104102/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class

this is for reference

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest you declared it as 
.SetLoction.setLocationActivity
but 
the package name is com.WAPP.SetLocation
so you need to prefix that again.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.WAPP.SetLocation",
                           "com.WAPP.SetLocation.SetLocation.setLocationActivity");
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to not registering your next activity XML file in the manifest. Register your next activity XML file in the AndroidManifest.xml file

`<activity android:name=".NextActivity" />`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thia might be problem if ImageView is used :(

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,ImageView.class);
                        intent.putExtra("imageurl",clients_document_return.getUrl());
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

and your class name might me Imageview.class
so first check all small capital in class name

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters this issue specifically for react native:

If you're using firebase dynamic links on Android 13, you need to explicitly define the host and scheme in your `AndroidManifext.xml`

Let's say your dynamic link looks like this:

```
https://example.page.link/?link=https://www.example.com/someresource&apn=com.example.android&amv=3&ibi=com.example.ios&isi=1234567&ius=exampleapp
```

You need to set the host to `example.com` and scheme to `https`

The reason is in Android 13, non-matching intents are blocked
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-all#intents

Example:

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        >
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
          android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <data
                android:host="sample.com" //You need to add other domains if you have more than one link.
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
```

This issue helped a lot
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/4198