# Activity Not recognized in Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make a simple program where if I go and click a button in my app a new activity pops up that asks to input a browser. Here's the Exception I keep recieving:

```
02-26 04:38:11.900 1937-1937/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
        {com.course.example.widgets/com.course.example.widgets.WebLookup};
    have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
        at com.course.example.widgets.Widgets.onClick(Widgets.java:139)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.course.example.widgets"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Widgets"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.course.example.widgets.WebLookup"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
</manifest>
```

Here's the code that actually starts the activity:

```
case R.id.webButton:{
    Intent webLookup = new Intent(this, WebLookup.class);
    startActivity(webLookup);
    break;
```

It's in a switch block that is for determining 3 other button actions but I didn't think it was relevant.

Here's a picture of XML file and my two Java files in navigator on left.

[image]

Comment: Disregard the two existing answers. Please tell us the capitalization you used in the actual file name for your class and show us the capitalization you used in the class name of your class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [...have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699192/have-you-declared-this-activity-in-your-androidmanifest-xml)

Comment: You have to provide complete package name.

Comment: Thank you, for the input however I tried putting the complete package name as shown above and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

**Declare this Activity to AndroidMenifest**, you error might be **have not written package name before activity name**

```
<activity
            android:name=".WebLookup" //write package name before activity name
            android:configChanges="orientation" //optional
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" //optional
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" /> //optional
```

Comment: Tried doing full location as shown above, but still did not work

Comment: This is working solution may be you are doing something wrong. write packagename.activity name where your activity is. check that properly.

Comment: okay. under com.course.example.widgets make one more package and try

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107789/android-error-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class

Comment: Why would making another package affect it? Are you saying to put WebLookup in a separate package?

Comment: yes, try that if this answer and link above doest work.

Comment: yup. it was the package name. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

If you have not included the package path at the top of the class you wont be able to reference it in the manifest, e.g.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding this activity class manually, verify that the class is set to public. This way the AndroidManifest.xml should automatically show your activity class as a possible option.

```
public MyActivityClass extends AppCompatActivity{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<activity android:name="com.course.example.widgets.WebLookup"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

the full name of the activity is much more comfortable in practice.

com.course.example.widgets.WebLookup mean the full path to your Activity class file.

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide complete package name like this

```
<activity android:name="com.course.example.widgets.WebLookup"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Otherwise it will not detect your class whom to transfer the intent.